# ftp: accessing files in subfolder without compromising root and recursive

Tags: permissions, ftp

Aloha.
I am curious if there is a way to give certain users access to subfolders of my domain via ftp, yet not access to any root files or other folders, for that matter.

Purpose: I am configuring a CMS which uses ftp to allow editors to modify defined files with their tags embedded.

CMS: http://www.cushycms.com/

FTP client: FileZilla

I develop on subfolders of one of my domains and want to test, yet I'd rather not give the username and password to my root and entire domain structure, just the folder that I am developing in. Is there a way to create a specific username and password for just the subfolder that will work for this CMS and not give up access to the whole tree?

This may seem link an FTP layman's task (I'm hoping it is) so apologies if I sound 'newbie' in this matter, just not an FTP wiz. I couldn't find anything helpful with search and the documentation & wiki were a bit technical for me.

Comment: Your FTP client is FileZilla, is that also what the server is running?

Comment: I removed my answer since it didn't pertain to your question.  Sounds like it is specific to Cushy, and their documentation looks pretty terrible.  Sorry!